# Lubuntu Task Manager always shows CPU usage at 100% even at idle

Tags: lubuntu, cpu, cpu-load

Is there a way to find out what application is causing the high CPU? Top shows nothing eating up the CPU. Even at idle my CPU is at 100%. Never changes. Never goes down. Always at 100% no matter what.

%Cpu(s): 35.2 us, 64.8 sy These two figures always add up to 100% no matter what. If one goes down in value the other immediately goes up to equal 100%. Always.

Is this harmful to the CPU? Is there a fix?

Lubuntu 13.10 768MB RAM P4 Dell

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways of measuring your CPU load. Take a look at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)

Generally, I use the uptime command to see if the computer is overloaded. For example:

jmhal@pluto:~$ uptime
 08:32:27 up 8 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.75, 0.67, 0.39

If the three numbers of you load average are bellow your number of cores, then your system is running fine.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Here is my uptime at idle upon a fresh boot: 14:10:19 up 14 min,  2 users,  load average: 2.22, 2.16, 1.44

Comment: How many cores does your computer have? If it is more than two, there is no problema. But if it exactly two or less, I think your computer is overloaded.